# How can I use a variable substitution in this javascript code

Tags: javascript, json, filter

How can I use the name variable in this function?

```
function filter(name, value) {
    return data.filter(d => d.name == value);
}
```

I got just an
Uncaught ReferenceError: d is not defined

Comment: why do you think `== name`  wont work.

Comment: myabe you data contains an undefined object?

Comment: In my data obj is no key name. I try to set the key (eg. vmax which exists) with the name variable. Is it possible to substitute the d.  ?

Comment: If you mean you want to use `name` as a way to access the property then you just use `[]` notation, eg `d=> d[name] == value`.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for :-) Thanks a lot Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the property of an object with the syntax `object[property]`. So this is the solution to your case:

```
function filter(name, value) {
   return data.filter(d => d[name] == value);
}
```